# Facing SqlException error in an Asp.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

[image]

Hello, I'm a novice in Asp.NET... I'm learning `Asp.net MVC` from the asp.net website's tutorial series.I'm using VS 2015 IDE. I've just copy pasted the code from their tutorial in Visual Studio 2015. And the `SqlException` `error` showing in the image is an auto generated code by Visual studio. I just tried to create a project that uses `local database` with `entity framework`. But when running the project, getting this error. Anyone help me please.

Comment: check the connection string whether correct with desired informations.

Comment: Application not able to connect to SQL server. Correct your connectionstring.

Comment: My connection string looks like this.. `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcMovie-20160606121919.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMovie-20160606121919;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MovieDBContext"
   connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/>
  </connectionStrings>`

Comment: The second `<add/>` is added by me which is in the tutorial. here i've given a database name named `Movies.mdf` but didn't create the database in the project's `App_data` folder..  is that the error?  but they also didn't create any database in their tutorial.. then what's wrong here?             `<add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />` @RavindraKumarChallagandla

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use try-catch block, then you can identify exact reason/issue behind your code. Most probably this issue because of the error in connection-string in you application.

Comment: My connection string looks like this.. <connectionStrings> <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcMovie-2‌​0160606121919.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMovie-20160606121919;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> <add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> </connectionStrings>

Comment: The second <add/> is added by me which is in the tutorial. here i've given a database name named Movies.mdf but didn't create the database in the project's App_data folder.. is that the error? but they also didn't create any database in their tutorial.. then what's wrong here? <add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> @RINSONPOULOSETHATTIL

Comment: u don't need to create any database in the project's App_data folder,

**  <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="server=XYZ;database=MovieDBContext;Integrated Security=SSPI;providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />**
can u please try this code in your webconfig file, also ensure that u having a real-database named as 'MovieDBContext' in your SQL-databse. ok

Comment: thank you for your info. i've found out the problem. 've posted an answer here also.

Comment: Good bro.. grt effort

Answer (score 0):

I'm success to solve my problem. I just need to change my connection string's `Data source= (LocalDB)\v11.0` to `Data source= (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB` which is added by me. that's it.. thanks everyone